# date time is changing depending on environment

Tags: javascript

I am trying to get a range of all the days within the month (eg) January 1 - January 31 2020.
This part works however, after I do `.toISOString()` on the Date object the date is getting changed in the browser [Chrome](https://jsfiddle.net/ft6dnq39/) but not in a [Node application](https://repl.it/@ctfrancia/DelectableMeekAbility)

they are doing the same code which is:

```js
function dateFormat(month, year) {
  const startDate = new Date(year, month, 1)
  console.log('startDate', startDate)
  const endDate = new Date(year, startDate.getMonth() + 1, 0)
  console.log('endDate', endDate)
  const dto = {
    monthYear: {
      startDate: startDate.toISOString(),
      endDate: endDate.toISOString()
    }
  }

  console.log('dto before stringify', dto)
  console.log('dto', JSON.stringify(dto))
}
dateFormat(0, 2020)
```

what I would like is an JSON object that looks like this:

```json
{
    "monthYear": {
        "startDate": "2020-01-01T00:00:00.000Z",
        "endDate": "2020-01-31T00:00:00.000Z"
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Date function basically follows the environment in which it runs.

The browser returns a function corresponding to your region,

Typically, the server returns the utc time

For this reason, the global service manages the time in utc on the server, and displays the time in the local time at the front (browser) received.