# Why 1 day off when I try to convert date into toisostring in javascript?

Tags: javascript, typescript

I am trying to convert date object to ISOString() formate. But it return me 1 day off ( I mean it reduce 1 day ).

```js
var fromDate = { 
  day:4,
  month:5,
  year:2012
 }
 var fromDateString = new Date(fromDate.year+'-'+fromDate.month+'-'+fromDate.day)
 console.log(fromDateString.toISOString())
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Converting a string to a date in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5619202/converting-a-string-to-a-date-in-javascript)

Comment: Check this post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64464146/date-time-is-changing-depending-on-environment

Comment: Or simply: new Date(2022,6,1).toISOString() returns, for me, "2022-06-30..." which just seems like nonsense

Answer (score 0):

It is because of timezone, new Date() is in your current timezone, toISOString() is using standard timezone.

Comment: It depends on what result do you want. If you need ISO String, that is correct. If you need local result, just use toString(), or do the format by yourself.

Answer (score 0):

I have searched and I find best solution for every date object to convert in any format.
Comment if you agree?

```js
var dateObj = {
  day:2,
  month:5,
  year:2012
}
var date = new Date;
date.setFullYear(dateObj.year,dateObj.month-1,dateObj.day)
console.log(date)
```